# How to generate the input table to BTm from partial rankings

Tags: r

I want to fit a Bradley-Terry model to many observers' rankings of three objects from within a larger set of objects.

My raw data looks like this:

```
obs1=c("A","C","D")
obs2=c("B","D","E")
obs3=c("C","B","E")
obs4=c("C","D","E")
obs5=c("C","E","D")
data=cbind(obs1,obs2,obs3,obs4,obs5)

    obs1 obs2 obs3 obs4 obs5
1   A    B    C    C    C
2   C    D    B    D    E
3   D    E    E    E    D
```

but what I need as an input to `countsToBinomial{BradleyTerry2}` and then to `BTm{BradleyTerry2}` is a table like below, which contains the number of times the column-name objects were ranked before the row-name object by the five observers.
All information I found begins with the counts as data, but since my number of observations is very high, I wonder if there is a way of automatising this transformation.

```
    A    B    C    D    E
A   0    0    0    0    0
B   0    0    1    0    0
C   1    0    0    0    0
D   1    1    3    0    1
E   0    2    3    2    0
```

Any ideas highly appreciated!

Comment: It can be done using two nested for loops, but does your data have only A to E or it can be more values as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's the answer using nested for loops and `match`...

```
x <- unique(as.vector(data))
x <- sort(x)
cmatrix <- matrix(0,nrow = length(x), ncol = length(x))
colnames(cmatrix) <- x
row.names(cmatrix) <- x
```

This creates your output matrix as `cmatrix` with initial values all 0. Then we run the loops as follows...

```
count <- 0
for (i in 1:ncol(cmatrix) ){
    for (j in 1:nrow(cmatrix) ){
        for (k in 1:ncol(data)){
            if( is.na(match(colnames(cmatrix)[i],data[,k])) == FALSE){
            if( is.na(match(row.names(cmatrix)[j],data[,k])) == FALSE){
            if( match(colnames(cmatrix)[i],data[,k]) < match(row.names(cmatrix)[j],data[,k]) ){count <- count+1} 
            }
            cmatrix[j,i] <- cmatrix[j,i]+count
            }
            count <- 0
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you required output table. This solution will work for any number of values and not just for A to E.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gaurav, this is perfectly helpful! I indeed have variable numbers of ranked objects and it works with any number.